# Where can I find the RXUI Javascript 'Time Flies' example?

Tags: javascript, system.reactive, reactive-extensions-js

About two years ago, there was an awesome RXUI-For-Web prototype from Microsoft Research, that came with an example html page that animated the text 'Time flies like an arrow' across your page as you moved your mouse.  I have been trying to find the prototypes again, but MS research has reorganized those pages and I can't find the original example projects again.  Does anyone know where this has moved to?  Does anyone know an alternate location I can find the original 'Time Flies' example at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Randomly came accross both this question and an apparrently working example [over on github](http://reactive-extensions.github.com/RxJS-Examples/timeflies/timeflies.html). :)

Comment: That's the one!! Thanks a bunch, I love this demo.  Great example showing the power of Rx, and I quite appreciate the pun!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the sample isn't included in the current git repository. The team is working on updating the repository with newer bits. You may find it reappear and fly faster at some point. I think you can still find the sample in the RxJs 1.0 download at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577610#js. The blog post explaining the code is available at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jeffva/archive/2010/03/17/reactive-extensions-for-javascript-the-time-flies-like-an-arrow-sample.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage. Unfortunately the post online doesn't work any more because it used a version of RxJs that is no longer available (getting a 502 error).